# Redirect each single page to via 3 Domains

Tags: redirect, url-scheme, spoofing

I wanna redirect a pages from domain.com to domain.tk to domain.eu and each page have unique url
Or if there's a wp plugin

Like this website:
https://apnetv.to/Hindi-Serial/show/226827/Bigg-Boss-e this website

I find how to redirect domain to another but it's not effective for me bcz I need to redirect each single page

Comment: What HTTP server are you using? Are you serving static pages or are the page contents created using something Node.js, PHP, Python or Perl? Do you want to implement HTML `<meta>` redirects or HTTP 301?

Comment: I use  Amazon aws
Content be added at WordPress dashboard. I wanna redirect my urls from many domains and each url redirect in same domains